# splitting a character array into a cell array and matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a text file.

In the file is approx 20,000 rows of data. Each row has one column & contains 256 characters (which are all numbers).

I need to split each row into a cell array or matrix. So each 8 characters are "one piece" of information. I want to split the first 3 characters into a cell array and the next 5 characters into a double, then same again for the next 8 characters.

```
 example

 1653256719812345

 myCellArray (1 x 2)     myDoubleArray (1 x 2)
 [165, 198]              [32567, 12345]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The example you have provided shows 16 characters, but you've only provided what it looks like for 8 characters.  What is the expected output format? Would it be a 2D matrix or cell array of numbers where we see 3 numbers then 5 numbers, then 3 numbers then 5 numbers....etc.?

Comment: apologies just realised my output wasn't very clear. So in the update above for the example you can see there are two arrays, 1 x 2 & another 1 x 2. If there were 50 rows with each column 16 chars long the two matrices would be 50 x 2. If the columns increased to 32 chars the matrices would be 50 x 4

Comment: Using `regexp` you can avoid having to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `regexp`. If the file `data.txt` contains

```
1653256719812345
1563256719812345
1233256719812345
1463256719812345
```

Then the following MATLAB statements will read the numbers.

```
>> txt = fileread('data.txt') % Read entire file in txt
>> out = regexp(txt,'(\d{3})(\d{5})(\d{3})(\d{5})','tokens') % Match regex capturing groups

out = 

{1x4 cell}    {1x4 cell}    {1x4 cell}    {1x4 cell}
```

Each cell in `out` is a row from the file containing the parsed numbers as strings.You can use `str2double` to convert the numbers to a numeric data type in MATLAB

```
>> nums = cellfun(@str2double,out,'uni',0)

nums = 

[1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]    [1x4 double]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html).

```
fid = fopen(MyFileName.txt);
data = textscan(fid, '%3d%5d', 'Delimiter', '');
fclose(fid);
```

testing:

```
% Test with string of 256 random digits that all happen to be 1:8 repeated 32 times
x = '1234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678123456781234567812345678';

>> y = textscan(x, '%3d%5d', 'Delimiter', '')
y = 

[32x1 int32]    [32x1 int32]

>> y{1}
ans =

     123
     123
     123
     123
     ...
```

I don't know the exact format of your files, so you may have to do this line-by-line within a loop (in which case you would get each line using `fgetl` and then replace `fid` in the `textscan` statement with the output from `fgetl`).

In general, whenever you find yourself having to read in data that was produced by FORTRAN code (fixed field width text files), `textscan`'s `'Delimiter, ''` and `'Whitespace', ''` parameters are your friend.

Comment: the data being provided is actually coming in as 20000 x 1 cell. When I do the following line it returns a 1 x 2 empty cell, taking im doing something wrong? x = textscan(y, '%3d%5d');

Comment: Two possible things. First, you skipped the `'Delimiter', ''` part. In your case here, MATLAB is taking just the first 8 characters and then going to the next delimiter character which is the end of the line. Second, you need to pass in text. So if you pass in a cell, you'll get nothing. You need to pass in `y{1}` to get a text array. If the elements of your cell array are already numeric, then this won't work at all and you need to rewrite your question because that is a completely different problem.

Comment: just added the 'Delimiter','' part still the same. The data comes in a 20,000 x 1 cell. I then convert the cell array to a char array of 20,000 x 256. Then I try x = textscan(geo, '%3d%5d', 'Delimiter', ''); Is that still wrong?

Comment: We are getting into the realm where the fact that I don't have your data makes it very difficult for me to debug your code. You're going to have to read the `texscan` help page and try a few different things on your own. For instance, does `x = textscan(geo(1, :), '%3d%5d', 'Delimiter', '');` work to read only the first line? If so, then the newline character is messing you up and you may have to do a loop and read each line separately. Are you sure that your data is all numeric? If there are any letters or unprintable characters, that'll mess things up, too.

Comment: For the record, I tried defining `X = [x;x;x;x];` from my code above, which should mimic the first 4 lines of your data, and plugged it into `textscan` and it worked just fine. The only trick was that it reads the data row-wise, so I got different answers if I plugged in `X` or `X'`. Always make sure you do some sanity checking on your answer.

Comment: thanks, I had to loop every line when using textscan

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your rows one by one and run something like the following code.

```
k=int2str(1653256719812345);
> myCellArray{1}=k(1:3)

myCellArray = 

    '165'

>> mydoublearray(1)=str2num(k(4:9))

mydoublearray =

      325671
```

If there's some formulaic pattern you should incorporate that instead of manually hard coding it.